# Principal Component Analysis w/ Alternating Least Squares for Missing Data

Tags: matlab, octave, pca, missing-data, least-squares

In MATLAB R2014b there is a new function, **`pca()`**, that performs PCA that can handle missing data. In the documentation it says that it performs pca  with the "alternating least squares" algorithm in order to estimate the missing values.

I would like to know if there are any practical references in how to apply PCA with this algorithm without the use of the function, or if there is a good reference on als. The reason is, there is no such function in Octave that can handle missing data and so I would like to code it myself.

Comment: The [documentation for `pca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) lists references at the bottom. I assume that those contain the information you are after.

Comment: Did you try `type pca` on the command prompt? If it is not built-in, you should be able to see the source code. Try looking up the documentation as well, as suggested by @Schorsch.

Comment: unfortunately pca is not a defined function in octave, so I don't have access to the source code. In the documentation, as Scorsch mentioned, there are references at the bottom that link to the academic paper. It is quite a long read...I guess I have no choice but to start with that unless anybody else has ideas.

Comment: to elaborate on my above comment, I also do not have access to matlab, so I can't determine whether or not the function is built-in

Comment: So I guess you will have to either go by @Schorsch's suggestion or have someone who has access to the PCA function to send you the source code.

Comment: I think the MATLAB pca algorithm "als" is implemented using [5] from the MATLAB references list: "EM Algorithms for PCA and SPCA", Sam Roweis.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I went through the references and was able to find their matlab code on the als algorithm from two of the references. For anybody wondering, the source code can be found in these two links:

http://research.ics.aalto.fi/bayes/software/index.shtml
https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I went through the references and was able to find their matlab code on the als algorithm from two of the references. For anybody wondering, the source code can be found in these two links:

1) http://research.ics.aalto.fi/bayes/software/index.shtml
2) https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/code.html